# How to make line width and text width bigger in R ternary plot?

Tags: r, plot

I am looking for solutions in vcd or base (or possibly others), but preferably not ggplot2. For example In the toy script below, I'd like to increase the width of the lines in the blue triangle (pch=2 point), the font size of the axis names and I'd also like to be able to move them further from the corners. In ternaryplot the traditional commands of `lwd` does not work.

```
require(vcd)
x = matrix(runif(30),10,3)

ternaryplot(x,  grid=FALSE, 
            pch=20, cex=1, col=1, 
            dimnames=c('name\n1','name\n2','name\n3' ))
ternaryplot(matrix(x[8,],1,3),
            cex=1.5, col='blue', pch=2, 
            new=F, grid=F, bg="transparent")
# add custom grid
    top <- sqrt(3)/2
    xlim <- c(-0.03, 1.03)
    ylim <- c(-1, top)
    pushViewport(viewport(width = unit(1, "snpc")))
    pushViewport(viewport(width = 0.8, height = 0.8, xscale = xlim, 
                          yscale = ylim, name = "plot"))
    grid.lines(c(0.5, 0.00), c(.29, 0))
    grid.lines(c(0.5, 1), c(.29, 0))
    grid.lines(c(0.50, 0.50), c(top,.29))
    upViewport(2)
```

An idea I had that ultimately failed was to try and place a transparent regular plot on top of the ternary plot, and do the drawing and labeling in there. I would also like to know how to do a regular plot and a ternary plot side by side.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with the facilities of `ternaryplot`, you will need to do some hacking. The 'dimnames' are built with `grid.text` and the number of parameters (one) is set up as very limited:

```
grid.text(x = 0.25 - 2 * eps - shift, y = 0.5 * top + 
            shift, label = dimnames[2], rot = 60, 
            gp = gpar(col = dimnames_color)) # three such calls
```

Likewise the outer boundaries of the ternary plot (which appears to be how you are constructing that inner triangle) are built with `grid.polygon` and the 'gpar' argument only accepts two arguments:

```
grid.polygon(c(0, 0.5, 1), c(0, top, 0), gp = gpar(fill = bg, 
        col = border), ...)
```

You can copy the code, edit to add additional `gpar` arguments, and then assign to `ternaryplot2` or a name of you choosing. I cannot tell if it's needed, but you may need to finish this off with:

```
  environment(new_plot_name) <- environment(ternaryplot)
```

Comment: by blue triangle I meant the pch=2 point, sorry I should have made that more clear. I edited the question.

Comment: I was just a bit surprised that you would use a call to ternaryplot just to make a small triangle around the point determined by the 8th row .... if I understand what is happening. And as I said the 'lwd'-parameter is not set up as one that currently gets passed to grid.polygon, but it wouldn't be that difficult to hack it into the code.